# How to input just one at scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

```
char command[6];
int command_num=0;
scanf("%s %d", command, &command_num);
```

If command is "top", I want to input only command, not command_num.
But when i input just command, input is continue.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You can use two scanf calls. If first one leads to command input "top", then skip the next scanf (put the second scanf call inside an if statement).

Comment: "If command is "top", ... input ... not command_num." Did you consider to take that as pseudo code and writing a few lines of code accordingly? How does that look? How does it fail?  Please provide a [mre] of your attempt, the input you use for testing, the test results and what has you stuck.

Comment: Input to a string `str` using `fgets`, then `int res = sscanf(str, "%5s %d", command, &command_num);` You will know from `res` how many terms were entered. Note that I restricted the length, this is particularly important when you provide such a tiny buffer `command[6]`.

Comment: Indeed, note that any `stdin` input from keyboard in standard C is line-based, and you are basically always better off if your code matches this behavior. In other words, use `fgets` (or `getline` on Unix/Linux, or write your own _getline_, because `fgets` is a bit of a hassle if you don't want to get confused by overlong lines) to read entire lines. Then parse those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is basically pseudo code, just translate it to C:

```
char command[LARGE_ENOUGH]; // probably no reason to allocate just 6 bytes

if(scanf("%s", command) != 1) // read only command and check result
{ 
  /* handle error - abort program etc */
}

if(strcmp(command, "top") != 0) // if command wasn't top
{
  if(scanf("%d", &command_top) != 1)
  {
    /* handle error - abort program etc */
  }
}
```

Place this all in a `while` loop if needed.

However, a better solution might be to take the input as string and accept digits in the string as commands.